# how can i group-with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My stock_comments table as below

```
id|user_id|stock_id|comment|
1 |   8   |    6   | stock comment one
2 |   8   |    6   | stock comment two
3 |   8   |    6   | stock comment three
4 |   8   |    6   | stock comment four
5 |   9   |    7   | stock comment one
6 |   9   |    7   | stock comment two
```

My controller as below

```
 $stock_comments = StockComment::where('stock_id' , $id)->where('comment_type' , 'recommendation')->groupBy('current_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

How can I keep array comments based on individual user_id?
Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: bring the comments table according to the same user_id(group_by)

Comment: Can't you add an where clause? `where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)` as you have added others?

Comment: enough `where('stock_id',$id)`